# How do I pass multiple ints into a vector at once?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, push-back

Currently when I have to use `vector.push_back()` multiple times.

The code I'm currently using is

```
std::vector<int> TestVector;
TestVector.push_back(2);
TestVector.push_back(5);
TestVector.push_back(8);
TestVector.push_back(11);
TestVector.push_back(14);
```

Is there a way to only use `vector.push_back()` once and just pass multiple values into the vector?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you copy the contents of an array to a std::vector in C++ without looping?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259297/how-do-you-copy-the-contents-of-an-array-to-a-stdvector-in-c-without-looping)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Try pass array to vector:

```
int arr[] = {2,5,8,11,14};
std::vector<int> TestVector(arr, arr+5);
```

You could always call [std::vector::assign](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign) to assign array to vector, call std::vector::insert to add multiple arrays.

If you use C++11, you can try:

```
std::vector<int> v{2,5,8,11,14};
```

Or

```
std::vector<int> v = {2,5,8,11,14};
```

Comment: the other two methods need enabled with C++11, if you use g++, compile it with `g++ -std=c++11`

Comment: But what if you need to pass multiple values *after* initialization. How would we do that without a lot of push_back calls?

Comment: But this will clear the previous contents. OP wants an equivalent of multiple push operations. I think the solution would then be to use a back inserter / vector::insert.

Comment: @David you can use `std::vector::insert`

Answer (score 154):

You can do it with initializer list:

```cpp
std::vector<unsigned int> array;

// First argument is an iterator to the element BEFORE which you will insert:
// In this case, you will insert before the end() iterator, which means appending value
// at the end of the vector.
array.insert(array.end(), { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 });
```

Comment: I prefer this answer to the accepted one since it does work on non-empty vectors.

Comment: I prefer this answer to the accepted one because it is a one-liner, which fits because it is a trivial use case

Comment: I prefer this answer because it is not restricted to initialization only. I was looking for a solution to add multiple new elements after the vector was initialized and containing data.

Comment: I'm getting an error adding the scalar: 
src//main.cpp:11:30: error: expected expression
        stack1.insert(stack1.end(), {2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9});
do you know why this could be?

Comment: A fine answer, although naming a vector "array" is not ideal.

Answer (score 78):

You can also use [vector::insert](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/).

```
std::vector<int> v;
int a[5] = {2, 5, 8, 11, 14};

v.insert(v.end(), a, a+5);
```

**Edit:**

Of course, in real-world programming you should use:

```
v.insert(v.end(), a, a+(sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])));  // C++03
v.insert(v.end(), std::begin(a), std::end(a));     // C++11
```

Comment: In C++11, there is the better solution `std::end(a)` available.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about it. Perhaps you can add it as a new answer?

Comment: That's a too small change worth a new answer. Let's just keep this as a comment (or you can edit your answer).

Comment: a+5 not good. Use a+(sizeof(a)/sizeof(int)) . No need to update that statement every time you add elements to "a".

Comment: @DivyangPatel, and even better is to use a+(sizeof(a)/sizeof(*a)), which works for any array type (thus safer to copy-paste).

Comment: @DivyangPatel I know that :) But I like to keep example code short n' simple. Those who read it should know better than to to copy it verbatim. Frankly, `a+(sizeof(a)/sizeof(int))` looks clunky.

Comment: @sashoalm Your argument is valid. But mine was addition for real-life programming... :):)

Answer (score 5):

These are the three most straight forward methods:

1) Initialize from an initializer list:

```
std::vector<int> TestVector = {2,5,8,11,14};
```

2) Assign from an initializer list:

```
std::vector<int> TestVector;
TestVector.assign( {2,5,8,11,14} ); // overwrites TestVector
```

3) Insert an initializer list at a given point:

```
std::vector<int> TestVector;
...
TestVector.insert(end(TestVector), {2,5,8,11,14} ); // preserves previous elements
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use [Boost.Assignment](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html):

```
const list<int> primes = list_of(2)(3)(5)(7)(11);

vector<int> v; 
v += 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9;
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `c++17` you could use the following method:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<int> vec;
template<typename... T>
void vecPush(const T& ... x) {
    (vec.push_back(x), ...);
}

int main() {
    vecPush(4, 10, 4);
    for(const auto& a : vec)
        cout << a << " ";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: aka fold expressions

Answer (score 1):

These days (`c++17`) it's easy:

```
auto const pusher([](auto& v) noexcept
  {
    return [&](auto&& ...e)
      {
        (
          (
            v.push_back(std::forward<decltype(e)>(e))
          ),
          ...
        );
      };
  }
);

pusher(TestVector)(2, 5, 8, 11, 14);
```

EDIT: for the really adventurous (c++20):

```
template <typename F, class Tuple>
constexpr void operator|(Tuple&& t, F f)
{
  [&]<auto ...I>(std::index_sequence<I...>) noexcept(noexcept((f(std::get<I>(t)), ...)))
  {
    (f(std::get<I>(t)), ...);
  }
  (std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size_v<std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>>>());
}

std::forward_as_tuple(2, 5, 8, 11, 14) | [&](auto&& e){ TestVector.push_back(std::forward<decltype(e)>(e)); }
```

Comment: You are telling me that this is more readable and straightforward than simply multiple `push_back()`s?

Comment: @higuaro I couldn't/shouldn't copy other answers.

Answer (score -3):

Yes you can, in your case:

```
vector<int>TestVector;`
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{

    TestVector.push_back(2+3*i);
    
}
```

Comment: This solution avoids duplicating code, but the function push_back still gets called multiple times, probably not what the question asker wanted. (Code formatting is off, too.)

Comment: Ok he asked for using push_back for once but its functionality must be multiple i think