# adding multiple elements to c++ vector at once

Tags: c++, vector

I was wondering if it is possible to push_back multiple elements to c++ vector more easily

For example

I create 5 objects

```
A a1;
A a2;
A a3;
A a4;
A a5;
```

Currently, i push all of them back like this

```
vector<A> list;
list.push_back(a1);
list.push_back(a2);
list.push_back(a3);
list.push_back(a4);
list.push_back(a5);
```

I was wondering if this can be done more succinctly like vector list(a1, a2, a3, a4, a5)..etc Thanks!

Comment: this has already been answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14561941/passing-multiple-int-values-into-a-vector

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `C++11` you can use `vector`'s initializer-list constructor:

```
vector<A> list {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5};
```

If `C++11` isn't available you can use the `iterator` based constructor if you create a temporary array, but it's not as clean as the `C++11` solution:

```
A tmp_list[] = {a1, a2, a3, a4, a5};
vector<A> list(tmp_list, tmp_list + 5};
```

Comment: Also, there's `std::begin()` and `std::end()`.

Comment: Yes, but I meant to illustrate that the second version was pre-`C++11`, I'll edit to be more clear.

Comment: I have the feeling that this could be done more efficiently (less copies) by using a `std::ref` clone, but I don't have the drive to test it ;)