# Copying an array into another array in C++

Tags: c++, vector, copy

I have an array created like this:

```
std::vector<int> data(n);
```

I have another array `b` (c Array b[]) having n int values. I want to put these values into `data`:

```
for (int i =0 ; i<n, i++) {
    data[i] = b[i]; 
}
```

Is there any other method in C++ for copying an array into another arrays ?

Comment: Do you want to copy the elements of an existing array into another existing array? `std::copy` does the same without a hand-made loop.

Comment: [Answer can be found here using search functionality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/259297/how-do-you-copy-the-contents-of-an-array-to-a-stdvector-in-c-without-looping)

Comment: Do you need `data` for anything else once you've made the copy?

Comment: If both are actually vectors rather than arrays: `data = b`.

Comment: @Bathsheba Yes, I will need data , as this will be processed by other functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `b` is an `int[]` (that is, a C array) then you can do:

```
std::vector<int> data(b + 0, b + n);
```

If `b` is also a `std::vector` then you can just do:

```
std::vector<int> data = b;
```

Answer (score 3):

It's not entirely clear from your question, but if `b` and `data` are both `std::vector<int>`, then you can do five related things:

**Initializing** a new `data` with `b`

```
std::vector<int> data = b; // copy constructor
```

**Initializing** a new `data` with `b`

```
std::vector<int> data(begin(b), begin(b) + n); // range constructor
```

**Copying** `b` entirely into an existing `data` (overwriting the current `data` values)

```
data = b; // assignment
```

**Copying** the first `n` elements of `b` into an existing `data` (overwriting the current `data` values)

```
data.assign(begin(b), begin(b) + n); // range assignment
```

**Appending** the first `n` elements of `b` onto an existing `data`

```
data.insert(end(a), begin(b), begin(b) + n); // range insertion
```

You can also use `end(b)` instead of `begin(b) + n` if `b` has exactly `n` elements. If `b` is a C-style array, you can do a `using std::begin;` and `using std::end`, and the range construction/assignment/insertion will continue to work.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `copy` (but be sure that you have enough elements in the destination vector!)

```
copy(begin(b), end(b), begin(data))
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::vector<int> data(b, b + n);`

Comment: @user2799508 just change the name