# C++ vector.assign (contents of char array) works in WinXP-32, fails in Win10-64; why?

Tags: arrays, vector, c++98

On this [StackExchange topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259297/how-do-you-copy-the-contents-of-an-array-to-a-stdvector-in-c-without-looping), first answer and last comment upon that answer, I learned to assign the contents of my char array (which I just read from file) into my vector.  The following code works fine in Windows XP, 32-bit, Visual Studio 2010, but fails in Win10, 64-bit, Studio 2012.  Both projects use the Unicode character set.  The contents of the file myConfig.txt are (separated by tabs):

words   3   mobius  lagrange    gauss

I am a complete noob, so if some mistake seems too stupid for anyone to make, go ahead and assume I made it.

The code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>     
#include <string.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <tchar.h>

using namespace std;

vector<wchar_t> wvec;
int n;
wchar_t ss[256];
FILE* pfile;

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    fopen_s(&pfile,"myConfig.txt","r");
    fwscanf_s(pfile,L"%ls",&ss);
    wprintf(L"var name is %ls\n",ss);
    fwscanf_s(pfile,L"%d",&n); 
    printf("num words is %d\n",n);
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        fwscanf_s(pfile,L"%ls",&ss);
        wvec.clear();
        n=wcslen(ss);
        wprintf(L"vec empty %ls length %d\n",vec,vec.size());
        wvec.assign(ss,ss+n+1); // +1 to contain null char
        wprintf(L"vec sz %d filled %ls\n",wvec.size(),wvec);
    }
    printf("press Enter to finish\n");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

On the Win10 machine, the output says, in part, "vec sz 7 filled ???", when I run/debug from the development environment.  When I run the exe in the x64\Release folder, the corresponding line of output says "vec sz 5 filled ???", while the contents of myConfig.txt are exactly the same.

On the XP machine, the output is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Finally answered my own question:  [RTFM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ybhk9kc.aspx).  It should not be

```
fscanf_s(pfile,"%s",&s);
```

It should be

```
fscanf_s(pfile,"%s",s, _countof(s));
```

I dunno why it worked in XP (convenient #bytes/char?) but, whatever.