# How I can insert an array of floats returned by a lambda into a vector of floats?

Tags: c++, lambda

I'm trying to make the following code to work

```
auto createMyArray = []() {
  float foo[] = {0.0f, 1.5f, 2.0f};
  return foo;
};

auto myArray = createMyArray();

std::vector<float> myVector;

// fatal error: no matching function for call to 'begin'
myVector.insert(myVector.end(), std::begin(myArray), std::end(myArray));
```

The issue is that createMyArray returns a pointer to the array and I'm not sure if it will be a good idea to try dereference it.

Also I'm getting the following warning

```
warning: address of stack memory associated with local variable 'foo' returned [-Wreturn-stack-address]
    return foo;
```

Which has sense because I'm not using new to create the array since I want to avoid heap allocations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modern C++ way of dealing with such arrays is to use `std::array`. That should avoid the problems you are facing.

Using a native C array like you do gets you into allocation-related problems which you should avoid. The compiler warning you are seeing is not to be taken lightly (like any warning). It tells you that `foo` points to memory that falls out-of-scope outside your lambda. It is quite likely to be overwritten by the `myVector` object you create after the call to `createMyArray()` and any further reference to `foo`'s elements may give you garbage.

Apart from that see the helpful answers here: [How do you copy the contents of an array to a std::vector in C++ without looping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/259297/how-do-you-copy-the-contents-of-an-array-to-a-stdvector-in-c-without-looping)

Comment: In the end I used std::array and just used a function to create it avoiding the lambda

Answer (score 1):

After exiting the lambda expression the local array will not be alive. So the code has undefined behavior.

But there is no need to use a lambda to insert an initializer list in a vector.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<float> myVector;
    
    myVector.insert( std::end( myVector ), {0.0f, 1.5f, 2.0f} );
    
    for ( const auto &item : myVector ) std::cout << item << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
0 1.5 2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::back_inserter` to copy elements into the vector appending at the end

```
std::copy(myArray, myArray + 3, std::back_inserter(myVector));
```

Or

```
myVector.insert(myVector.end(), myArray, myArray + 3);
```

By the way the array created in lamba function is stack allocated, which means array will no longer exist after the execution of lamba function, instead use dynamic memory allocation using `new` or `std::array`

Comment: It is not true that the insert() method is not applicable. OP is just using it wrong (coupled with wrong use of stack-allocated native array).